# Thermistor control of peltier voltage with Arduino (for DSLR chill box project)

Tags: arduino, voltage, relay, thermistor, peltier

I am mildly familiar with electronics, mostly from playing around with electronics kits as a kid. That was a long time ago, though, maybe as much as 20 years ago. I am currently working on a cold or "chill" box for my Canon 5D III, so I can keep it's temperature very low, and very consistent, for doing low noise astrophotography.

I have a general design for the box, and I'm using a single 12v 5.8amp peltier (TEC) attached directly to a copper box for cooling. The box is currently insulated with extruded foam board, and the hot plate of the peltier will be cooled with a water cooler from an old computer kit.

I'm getting more ambitious with my project, however. I want thermal regulation, to maintain a consistent temperature, and I'd eventually like to get into two-stage cooling to achieve a Delta-T of closer to -55-60°C relative to ambient (the chill box will be cooling the camera, so the sensor will be warmer, probably by as much as 10°C, than the temperature of the copper plating in the box itself.) I want to have two primary modes:

1. Rapid cooling mode, operating the peltier at 12v or higher (max voltage is 15.4v) to quickly cool the box down to the target temperature.
2. Regulated maintenance mode, operating the peltier at lower voltages to maintain a consistent temperature, above the maximum potential cooling the peltier can supply (for headroom as the voltage is adjusted in response to small temperature fluctuations).

I'd like to maintain temperature within 2-3°C if possible. I've looked into Arduino (and I've messed with similar things in the past), and it seems perfectly ideal for the task, with one exception: It doesn't seem to handle the kind of current I need top power a single peltier, and certainly not two.

I've done some research on how I might achieve this, but I'm falling up short on my understanding of the electronics involved. I've found a two-relay "shield" for Arduino Uno that can power two devices with up to 8amps each, and up to 30v each. That can be controlled from the Arduino itself. It seems the design of a relay uses a magnetic coil to actuate a switch that allows an independent power source to be used to power components like a motor, solenoid, or in my case a peltier. I haven't found any way of actually regulating the voltage of the relay with the Arduino, however.

So I kept investigating, and I came across some schematics that showed how to use transistors, specific mosfets to be exact, where the base was connected to an Arduino output, and the collector/emitter were connected to the power loop of whatever needed to be powered at a higher voltage (not sure about current here), and this still allowed control of the voltage.

It's been so long since I messed with any of these components, my memory is extremely rough, and I'm not quite connecting how it all works. I'd be happy with some references to complete examples of powering, and controlling the voltage of, high powered devices via an Arduino, but if anyone here can explain how all this works and why, that would be most ideal. I'd rather understand the concepts, so I can reapply them later, than just have a pattern to follow.

Comment: I'm working on a similar [camera cooling project](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/116271/is-it-more-efficient-to-stack-two-peltier-modules-or-to-set-them-side-by-side).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Good question, but you've touched on various things that require some explanation.  The answer isn't as simple as you probably hoped if you want to do this right.  There are a number of issues.

Usually power is modulated by PWM nowadays.  PWM stands for *pulse width modulation*, and means that you alternate quickly between slamming something full on and full off.  If you do this fast enough, the device receiving the power sees only the average.  This is so common that most micrcontrollers have PWM generators built in.  You set up the hardware with a specific period, then all you have to do is write a new value to some register and the hardware automatically changes the *duty cycle*, which is the fraction of the time the output is on.  You can run a DC brushed motor at a few 10s of Hz PWM, and it can't tell the difference between that and the average DC.  To keep it from making audible whine, you might run it at 24 kHz PWM.  Switching power supplies work largely on this principle, and run from high 10s of kHz to 100s of kHz under processor control, or over a MHz from a dedicated chip.

One big advantage of driving things with on/off pulses is that no power is lost in the switch.  The switch can't dissipate any power when off since the current thru it is 0, or when on since the voltage accross it is 0.  Transistors make pretty good switches for this, and will only dissipate power as they are transitioning between the on and off states.  One of the upper limits on PWM frequency is to make sure the switch spends most of its time full on or full off and not much time in-between.

You might think that this sounds easy.  Just hook up the right kind of transistor as a switch to pulse the power to the Peltier, and drive it from the inevitable PWM output your microcontroller has.  Unfortunately, it's not that easy due to how Peltiers work.

The cooling power of a Peltier is proportional to current.  However, the Peltier also has some internal resistance that heats up due to current.  The heat dissipated by a resistor is proportional to the square of the current.  Both these effects compete in a Peltier cooler.  Since the internal heating goes with the square of the current, but cooling power is only proportional to the current, eventually there is a point at which additional current causes more heating than the additional cooling can get rid of.  That is the maximum cooling current, which is something the manufacturer should tell you up front.

Now you're probably thinking, OK, I'll PWM between 0 and that maximum cooling current (or voltage).  But, it's still not that simple for two reasons.  First the maximum cooling point is also the least efficient point (assuming you're smart enough not to run it higher than the maximum cooling point).  Pulsing at that point would result in the most power consumption for the amount of cooling, which also means the most heat to get rid of for the amount of cooling.  Second, large thermal cycles are bad for Peltiers.  All that differential contraction and expansion eventually breaks something.

So, you want to run a Peltier at some nice smooth voltage or current, varying only slowly to respond to temperature demands.  That works fine for the Peltier, but now you have a problem in the driving electronics.  The nice idea of a full-on or full-off switch not dissipating any power no longer applies.

But wait, it still can.  You just have to insert something that smooths out the on/off pulses before the Peltier sees them.  In fact, this is basically what switching power supplies do.  All the above was a way of introducing the solution, which I felt wouldn't have made any sense without the background.  Here is a possible circuit:

[image]

This looks more complicated than it is because there are two PWM-driven switches in there.  I'll explain why shortly, but for now just pretend D2, L2, and Q2 don't exist.

This particular type of N-channel FET can be driven directly from a microcontroller pin, which makes the driving electronics a lot simpler.  Whenever the gate is high, the FET is turned on, which shorts the bottom end of L1 to ground.  This builds up some current thru L1.  When the FET is switched off again, this current continues to flow (although it will decrease over time) thru D1.  Since D1 is tied to the supply, the bottom end of L1 will be a little higher than the supply voltage at that time.  The overall effect is that the bottom end of L1 gets switched between 0V and the supply voltage.  The duty cycle of the PWM signal on the gate of Q1 determines the relative time spent low and high.  The higher the duty cycle, the higher the fraction of the time L1 is driven to ground.

OK, that's just basic PWM thru a power switch.  However, note that this is not directly tied to the Peltier.  L1 and C1 form a low pass filter.  If the PWM frequency is fast enough, then very little of the 0-12 V peak-peak signal on the bottom of L1 makes it to the top of L1.  And, making the PWM frequency fast enough is precisely what we plan to do.  I'd probably run this at least at 100 kHz, maybe a bit more.  Fortunately, that's not really hard for many modern microcontrollers with their built-in PWM hardware to do.

Now it's time to explain why Q1, L1, and D1 are duplicated.  The reason is more current capability without having to get different types of parts.  There is also a side benefit in that the PWM frequency L1 and L2 together with C1 have to filter is twice what each switch is driven with.  The higher the frequency, the easier it is to filter out and leave only the average.

You want nearly 6A of current.  There are certainly FETs and inductors available that can handle that.  However, the kinds of FETs that are easily driven directly from a processor pin have some tradeoffs internally that usually don't allow for such high current.  In this case I thought it was worth the simplicity of being able to drive two FETs directly from processor pins than to minimize absolute parts count.  One larger FET with a gate driver chip probably wouldn't save you any money compared to two of the FETs I show, and the inductors will be easier to find too.  Coilcraft RFS1317-104KL is a good candidate, for example.

Note that the two gates are driven with PWM signals 180° out of phase with each other.  The capability to do that easily in hardware isn't quite as common as just PWM generators, but there are still many microcontrollers that can do that.  In a pinch you can drive them both from the same PWM signal, but then you lose the advantage of the PWM frequency the low pass filter needs to get rid of being twice that of each of the individual PWM signals.  Both halves of the circuit will be demanding current from the power supply at the same time, too.

You don't have to worry about exactly what voltage or current results to the Peltier from any one PWM duty cycle, although I'd figure out what results in the maximum cooling point and never set the duty cycle higher than that in the firmware.  If the supply voltage is the maximum cooling point, then you don't have to worry about it and you can go all the way to 100% duty cycle.

At the next level above the PWM duty cycle in the firmware you will need a control loop.  If done right, this will automatically drive the cooler hard initially, then back off as the temperature gets near the setpoint.  There are lots of control schemes.  You should probably look into PID (Proportional, Integral, Derivative), not because it's the best or most optimal, but because it should work well enough and there is a great deal of information on it out there.

There is a lot more to get into here, and tweaking the PID parameters could be a whole book on its own, but this is already getting very long for a answer here so I'll stop.  Ask more questions to get into more details.

### Filter part values

Mostly I pulled the inductor and capacitor values out of the air, but based on intuition and experience that these values would be plenty good enough.  For those not used to these things, here is a detailed analisys that shows the PWM ripple is indeed attenuated to oblivion.  Actually just getting it down to a few percent of the DC average would be good enough, but in this case they are clearly reduced to well below the levels that would matter.

There are several ways to look at a L-C filter.  One way is to think of the two parts as a voltage divider, with the impedance of each part being frequency-dependent.  Another way is to find the rolloff frequency of the low pass filter, and see how many times higher the frequncy is we are trying to attenuate.  Both these methods should result in the same conclusion.

The impedance magnitude of a capacitor and inductor are:

Z<sub>cap</sub> = 1 / ωC
Z<sub>ind</sub> = ωL

where C is the capacitance in Farads, L the inductance in Henrys, ω the frequency in radians/second, and Z the magnitude of the resulting complex impedance in Ohms.  Note that ω can be expanded to 2πf, where f is the frequency in Hz.

Note that the cap impedance descreases with frequency as the inductor impedance increase.

The low pass filter rolloff frequency is when the two impedance magnitudes are equal.  From the above equations, that comes out to

f = 1 / (2π sqrt(LC))

which is 734 Hz with the part value shown above.  The 100 kHz PWM frequency is therefore about 136 times this rolloff frequency.  Since that is well past the "knee" region of the filter, it will attenuate a voltage signal by the square of that, which is about 19k times in this case.  After the fundamental of a 12 Vpp square wave is attenuated 19,000 times, nothing of any consequence to this application will be left.  The remaining harmoics will be attenuated even more.  The next harmonic in a square wave is the third, which will be attenuated another 9 times more than the fundamental.

The current value for the inductors is whatever the peak current they must be able to carry.  I see I did make a mistake there, now that I'm looking at it more closely.  In a typcial buck converter, the peak inductor current is always a bit more than the average.  Even in continuous mode, the inductor current is ideally a triangle wave.  Since the average is the overall output current, the peaks are clearly higher.

However, that logic doesn't apply to this particular case.  The maximum current is at 100% PWM duty cycle, which means the 12 V is applied directly to the Peltier continuously.  At that point, the total average and peak inductor currents are the same.  At lower currents, the inductor currents are a triangle, but the average is also lower.  In the end, you only need the inductors to handle the maximum continuous output current.  Since the total maximum current thru the Peltier is about 6 A, each inductor only needs to be able to handle 3 A.  Inductors with 3.5 A rating would still work just fine, but 3 A inductors would also be good enough

Comment: Hi Olin, nice to see you. Thanks for the detailed answer. I am aware of PWMs, however I'd read a couple articles recently that indicated they may not be ideal for use with a peltier, so I'd stayed away. I'm aware Arduino usually has a number of channels that are PWM as well. I haven't read your entire answer yet, will need some time. I think I see what your getting at though. Any chance you could speak to the use of a PWM controller with a peltier?

Comment: @jrista: Read the whole answer, then let me know if you still have questions about Peltiers and PWM.  I tried to address the issues specifically, but I may need to add some clarification.

Comment: Thanks, I get the concept now. I also understand the point about high peltier thermal cycling, makes sense. I don't understand the specific component choices (i.e. why you chose L1 to be 100uH 3.5a, or C1 to be 470uF 20V, etc.), I'm hoping that's just a weak spot from not being an electronics expert, and not actually having messed with electronics for well over a decade. :P The only real question I have now is, can an Arduino do the more unique things (i.e. 180° phase differential for the PWMs)? I like Arduino for it's community, diversity, and programmability, and I can do a LOT with it.

Comment: Oh, regarding the peltiers. As far as I know, the optimum is 12v 5.8a. The range of voltage was something like 5v or 7v up through 15.4v. There wasn't any other mention of amperage, other than the 5.8a. I have identifier numbers on the tecs themselves, so I can probably look up more detailed information (I just picked up a box of 5 70W ones off of Amazon for pretty cheap (and, shipped from the US, rather than Hong Kong...I'm sure you can figure out my greatest concern there. :)).

Comment: Well, thanks for the answer! I now have a research direction, but I'm sure I'll be asking other questions very soon.

Comment: @jrista: I admit I picked the inductor and capacitor values just from what seemed plausible without doing the math. I'm pretty sure they will be fine upon closer inspection. I don't have time now, but perhaps tomorrow I'll add something about the component values. 3.5 A is some margin over half the max current.  The current thru the inductor will go up and down during each cycle, so the peak capability needs to be higher than the average.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Where can I find more details about the math that would help me solve these kinds of small problems on my own?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Olin. Very helpful. I am going to use this approach, seems very solid. The only issue I have now is finding a microcontroller that is easy to program, but also supports the ability to shift the phase of the PWMs. I purchased an Arduino, but it doesn't look like it really supports phase shifting. I really like the Arduino programmability...so that's really a bummer. I may ask a new question about finding a way to shift or delay the duty cycle of a PWM output...

Comment: @jrista: Using a 2-phase switcher is how I'd do it, but it can certainly be done with a single phase.  Since this is a one-off personal project and you are familiar with the arduino, just go with its capability and design the rest of the system around it.  You can get FETs and inductors good to 6 A, but probably not a FET that you can drive directly from a 5 V logic output.  In that case, use the circuit I show but drive each FET with the same signal.  Don't tie the gates together, buffer each one seperately for better drive, or have the micro make the same PWM signal on two pins.

Comment: If I use the inductor and capacitor off a single PWM (or even two with the same phase), will that smooth the power signal out enough that it won't damage the TEC?

Comment: @jrista: Yes.  With 100 uH and 470 uF you'll be fine either way.  The ripple will be higher with single phase, but still well below anything that will make any effective difference in efficiency.  At 100 kHz, efficiency is the main issue.  The individual cycles are so fast that the temperature change per cycle is so tiny as to not matter.  I shouldn't have made as big a deal of 2 phase as I did.  It's a nice to do, but you'll be fine with single phase.

Comment: Thanks, Olin. I'll see if I can find these parts and actually put this thing together.

Comment: One more question, Olin. As far as I can tell, the Arduino PWM can switch as fast as 8Mhz. It also seems limited in the choices you can make for frequency and duty cycle...frequency seems largely limited to powers of 2, and duty cycle is 0%, 10%, 25%, 50%, 80%, and 100%. Will any of that be a problem to achieving my goal here?

Comment: @jrista: You can chose the frequency over a reasonable range, but you need decent duty cycle resolution.  I doubt the native Atmel PWM is that limited, so this is apparently a limitation in the arduino sugar coating between you and the hardware.  Either use the hardware directly, or maybe a different arduino with a library that exports better PWM capabilities.  Take a look at Microchip's "PIC Kit"(?).  It's supposed to be arduino-compatible, but based on the much more capable PIC32 compared to the Atmel.  Maybe they provide better capabilities.

Comment: Looks like duty cycle is actually set by a byte, so any level from 0 to 255. That should give me enough flexibility, I think.

Answer (score 2):

You have the right idea, although there are some details that need attention.

First, unless you can provide really good insulation, a two-stage chill box may not be a reasonable approach. Two-stage coolers will indeed provide high temperature differentials, but only for very low cooling powers at the second face. Consider that, as a rule of thumb, a TEC can cool with only 10% efficiency. Your Peltier elements are about 70 watts, so a single stage can cool 7 watts (although probably not anywhere near your desired delta T.) This means that your second stage can only run at 7 watts total, not 70 watts, and in turn it can only suck out about .7 watts. Again, at this level you won't get big delta Ts. TEC manufacturers provide power/temp differential curves that you should examine. Making a camera enclosure that will only leak a half watt of thermal energy will be a task, especially since you need to couple it to a telescope. You can give it a try, but be prepared for disappointment.

Second, most Arduino CPU boards allow for PWM outputs, which are exactly what you need for modulating your TEC drive. However, you will need to sense the temperature of your chill box, and create a feedback loop in software. You can do this easily enough using, for instance, a thermistor and a resistor, with the thermistor attached to your chill box, but you do need to pay attention to what you're doing. Since temperature usually varies slowly for large objects, your PWM frequency does not need to be very high, and a solenoid driver might actually work. It's not a good idea in terms of long-term reliability, since relays usually have a limited number of switching cycles before the contacts get worn, but it might be a start. Solid state is better. Not only that, but you may need independent temperature control loops for each cooler.

And just as a last consideration, you'll need to find a way to keep your outer optical element from fogging up. It will be cold and prone to condensation from the outer air. This can be done by blowing dry air or nitrogen on it continuously,

Comment: Thanks for the response. Some questions about your statements about the TEC, though. I did some testing last night with several of the peltiers. Each one was able to cool the cold plate down to 35-37°F from the ambient temperature of 70°F, and sustain that temperature. That's a delta-t of about 35°F/20°C. I'm not sure how that translates into watts in the context of your answer, or how close to 70 or 7 watts that differential is. If doing a dual-stage cooler is difficult, maybe I should just use one peltier on either side of the cold box instead...

Comment: Oh, and to note...I think I was underpowering the peltiers. I grabbed an AC/DC adapter, and forgot to check the power rating on it. It was rated at 5 amps, so I'm not sure that the peltier, when it reached -20°C, was actually running as efficiently as it could (be that only 10% or higher.) I'm hoping that when it's fully and properly powered, it will run more efficiently, and maybe achieve 25-30°C delta.

Comment: Finally, regarding the optics and condensation. The cold box itself will be pretty heavily insulated, with 1" thick insulation material. The "telescope" is actually a Canon EF 600mm f/4 L II lens, which is covered in a neoprene LensCoat. The rear-most optical element in the lens is a good several inches from the lens mount in the camera. On top of that, I live in Colorado...the average humidity at my house is about 16%, maybe as high as 25% at some of the dark sites I image at. ;)

Comment: Driving a Peltier with PWM directly is a bad idea, *especially* at such low frequencies as you'd use with a relay being the switch.  See my answer for details why this is bad, but basically you run the Peltier at its least efficient point, and you will destroy it quickly due to thermal cycling.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast: Based on Olins answer, I think I understand yours better. When you mention the efficiency of a peltier is only about 10%, your basically referring to the amount of heat drawn from the cold plate to the hot plate, vs. the total dissipated head on the hot plate. With the difference being the energy generated by the peltier itself. Is that correct? Out of those 70 watts, around 7 watts are energy actually "cooled", while 63 watts are the heat energy actually generated by the peltier itself, simply as a consequence of having a current run through it?

Comment: @jrista - you got it.

Comment: Also, the problem with low temps is that, if your lens surface gets below freezing, you will get frost on it, and that can happen at quite low humidity. It may not be a problem depending on the details of heat flow in your box, but you should keep it in mind.

Comment: And another also. Just as an experiment, try putting your TEC cold face on a foam block and see how cold it gets. This will show you how well it performs when it doesn't have to suck out much heat. Even better, make a square depression the exact sixe and depth of the cooler, to minimize heat flow in from the edges. Plus, of course, see how well your heat sink is doing. What you want to do is keep the hot side as cool as possible.

Comment: Thanks WRB. It's amazing how inefficient these things are, although for their low efficiency, they ironically still seem to get the job done. I did have a little bit of frost during my tests last night. I wondered about putting a low volume fan inside the box to move the air around, not sure if that would help. I will probably be using water cooling too cool. I have an old Zalman copper heapipe with this huge set of copper fins, and it's almost as efficient, but it's huge and heavy, and that affects the balance and stability of the telescope.

Comment: Moving the air around in the box will help keep the camera uniformly cool, but it won't help the frost problem. What you might try is a second cooler which penetrates the box and makes a small object very cold. Run this for a while before you turn on the camera, and let it freeze out the moisture in the box. This won't help condensation on the optics outside the box, such as a window. Unless you deliberately heat the window, but this will increase the amount of power the main cooler has to remove. You can't win. And about weight and balance vs. capacity - welcome to real engineering.

Comment: You know, I have tons of desiccant. I'll just build the box with some perforated holders for desiccant, which should soak up the limited moisture here quite nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to understand how to design thermal cooling and heater defogging inside the camera .

Start by looking at existing designs.  You don't want to build a Mickey Mouse ice box and damage your D50.

http://www.centralds.net/en/astro60d.htm#safe

I have built a couple -50C ice boxes using dry ice @ 2$ a brick. and a 3W fan . -40C is easy. -50C is hard, while the ice measured -65C on the surface. I used a picnic box with 2" insulation foam.

You can use an old school square CPU heat sink for the Peltier cooler for the 2nd stage and use dry ice for the 1st stage from any Dairy factory...

with "loads" of dried desiccant ... at your own risk ... from chemical impact on your camera.

Warming up was regulated to 2 deg/min to reduce condensation risk.  and the hot box to 45C was created by dangling a 25 W soldering iron which I used for product testing, which you wont need, but you will need a heater inside your camera..

Comment: Interesting idea. It looks like this requires some heavy modification of the DSLR. I use my 5D III for all my normal photography as well, so I don't want to do any modding. I just need something that I can drop it into, attach a lens or telescope, and have it cool with a delta-T somewhere between 30-40°C. I know that won't cool as much as if I directly cooled the sensor assembly, but I already know that by the time the temperature drops to between -5°C and 0°C, noise is very low and very manageable (thanks to -8°C temps this February. ;))

Answer (score 0):

You can use PWM, you just need to make sure the frequency is high enough. Lots of people put filters on them because they are unable to run at frequencies higher than 100Hz, which is likely to slow. There are several vendors that back up this claim, but there are also several vendors that do not like it. Hence, there is a lot of misinformation going around. Personally, I have run peltiers with PWM with no issues.